# Do asked questions get an upvote by default?

Tags: support, questions, reputation, voting, upvotes

I always get 5 reputation, whenever I ask a new question and the question also seems to have 1 vote score right when it's asked.

So if questions get a *free* upvote whenever they are first asked, which upvoter is it ascribed to in the system. The Community user?

Does this system just grant 5 free reputation for every question asked? And why isn't this system abused? Is it protected by a periodical limit?

Comment: _"Do asked questions get an upvote by default?"_ No, that's not the case.

Comment: But do they give 5 reputation by default?

Comment: No, there's no 5 reputation received for any question by default.

Comment: possibly related: [The “First Posts” review queue is ineffective and toothless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170586/165773)

Comment: I don't get why there are four close votes here. This question is neither "unclear" nor "too broad".

Comment: Note, the meta site is far more antagonistic than the main. Don't worry on your downvoted and closed question, it only represents the general attitude of the MSO community, but not the attitude of the sane readers of the future. Furthermore, the votes what you get on the MSO, don't affect your reputation, and practically there is no automatic post ban here.

Comment: @peterh the downvotes here could easily mean the voters believed that the question is either not useful or poorly researched, as it doesn't seem very useful and a little bit of research would show that the premise of the question is false. Your attempt to invalidate those votes is rude and serves only to confuse the OP more.

Comment: @TinyGiant I can't invalidate any votes. I find your false accusation an insult, and calling the OP "confused" also insulting. He is not confused, he is curious, that is all. The answer of this wonderful community: 7 downs and 4 close votes until now. **This is what should be fighted.**

Comment: So... On which tags do we get that free upvote that you are talking about? :)

Comment: @peterh you attempt to invalidate votes by saying that they don't mean anything when they actually do. I personally find this question not useful and it shows an extreme lack of research effort so the votes are entirely warranted. My accusation is fact-based. whether or not you want to be insulted by the truth is up to you. What should be fought against is the misinformation you insist on spreading that serves only to confuse.

Comment: @TinyGiant Not this is what I said. I said that they represent the general attitude of the MSO community, which is very different from the general attitude of the sane readers of the future.

Comment: @E_net4 (sorry for the offtopic) Dig the SEDE, questions on some tags are treated surprisingly well...

Comment: @peterh: your very own interpretation of how voting works and why people cast them is not doing anyone any favours. Yes, you are actually wrong, your assertions about why people vote a minority opinion and unless you have a mind-reading device can only be based on your own emotional interpretation of limited information. We all can only see that voting takes place, to assert that the voting is done for any specific reason or agenda, especially as antagonistic as your view, can’t be supported.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I only think, the MSO (and, in a lesser form, also the SO) are much more antagonistic, as it would be reasonable. To this opinion, I don't need to assume any reason behind the votes, even if I have. It is enough if I see many good-standing or not so bad posts, and their score.

Comment: @peterh: instead, your comments create an us-versus-them split that doesn’t exist or need to exist. By your very actions you conjure up conflict where there is none, make it harder for new users here to figure out how Meta works for themselves and so hinder more people from participating. It’s easy for me to know your opinions are just as over the top and applicable to the situation as [Denis the Constitutional Peasant](https://youtu.be/kCU2yWXyWg8)’s are, but I’m not sure that you yourself realise this. But the community here, me included, will not stop from educating the new users.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is my "own emotional interpretation of limited information" for you, is the basic human rationality for me. What is "constitutional peasant" for you, is a free spirit for me. What is "peasant" for you, is a volunteer contributor for me. What is "kingdom" for you, is free cooperation for me. And, what is "king" for you... my word is not CoC-compliant for that.

Comment: @peterh: "*He is not confused, he is curious, that is all.*" No, he is in fact confused. He sees X, and from that he infers that Y is true. But Z is actually true, and X does not necessitate Y. Therefore, his inference of Y from X represents being confused; that's what confusion *is*: incorrectly understanding the stuff that was presented to you. Oh, and "confused" is the charitable version; if you look at his account, X is not actually what he's seen. He's asked 8 questions, but only a couple have gotten upvotes at all. So the question is not even well evidenced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fact is that the people on the SO are there in their free time, and most of their contributions are being done because they want to, on various reasons. The ultimate power, what exists in a feudal country, here doesn't exist. Your power lies in the fact that these volunteer contributors help each other, sometimes even against the views you represent. It is a system of a company, a full profit-oriented company, what needs to create positive business results in a free-market country, and these results highly depend on our volunteer work. Please re-think your "kingdom model".

Comment: @NicolBolas Getting 5 ups and 1 down for 8 questions clearly reasons for a newbie, why he is feeling that. Thus, his question is fair, and no, he is not confused. Your other statements are imho agreeable, and in a more detailed form, they would have a better place in an answer.

Comment: @peterh: The OP said, "*I always get 5 reputation, whenever I ask a new question and the question also seems to have 1 vote score right when it's asked.*" Yet that is not actually true. Newbie or not, the facts do not fit the statement. That makes the question poorly researched. Stop pretending that newbies are some sub-human species that is incapable of telling the difference between "a thing that happened to me once" and "a thing that happens every time". The OP *can* tell the difference; they merely choose not to. That makes it a poorly researched question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, from which ressources do you think should I have derived this conclusion.
From multiple questions I asked now, each time I got an instant upvote.
The [Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) question in SE states that you get 5 rep/upvote, which is what I always got.
I couldn't find a similarly asked question before.
This question could have been a good frame of reference for the future, but this is SO after all.
So just taking my free answer and laugh at the next person asking the same question is all that's left to do.

Comment: @NicolBolas He did not know, probably he can't check, where he got the upvotes. He made the question, and he has got the ups, this is what he has seen. The questions are created in the lack of information, voting them down *in the lack of this information* is clearly something what inherently opposes the logic of the voting system itself on a Q/A site.

Comment: @peterh You can check who gave the upvotes? How do you do that?

Comment: @user10385242 No one can see that, not even the mods (the mods have a limited ability to check, if there is some suspicious about the votes).

Comment: Oh yikes, then I couldn't even have found out this way.

Comment: @user10385242: "*From multiple questions I asked now, each time I got an instant upvote.*" That is provably untrue. [This is the reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10385242/user10385242?tab=reputation) of your posting history. We can see your rep increase and decreases and thus see voting patterns. You have had precisely 4 upvotes. You asked 8 questions. It is *impossible* for all 8 of your questions to have gotten an upvote, when you have only gotten 4 upvotes.

Comment: @peterh: "*He did not know, probably he can't check, where he got the upvotes.*" Hence the poor research. He's been a user *for 6 months*. And sure, he may have been a sparse user, so he may not have stumbled onto the profile/account page. But why is it unreasonable to expect people to verify the stuff they say? My first question would have been to find out if you can check to see what the votes on your posts are, so that I could verify a claim before I made it. And even then, I'd probably have found a duplicate first.

Comment: @NicolBolas If you want to measure that, then you should not measure the time since the registration, because posting just 8 times in a half year is a very low activity. Actually, it is the reason, why he doesn't know very well the system. And it is also the reason, why he asked this question on the meta - he had all reasons to expect, that he will get the same nice result, as he got on the main site until now. The close reasons "too broad" and "unclear" are imho clearly false, the dupe might be right (please show the link). Note, he doesn't even know, where and how to research.

Comment: There's been many flags on this thread, can we stop the debate on what the OP knows/didn't know and the motives for people voting and stick to the issue at hand? There's no automatic upvotes.

Comment: Quick votes come from that it is new on queue and many people see the question

Answer (score -27, accepted):

You have currently 8 questions, for which you got probably 5 upvotes and 1 downvote. In general, compared to the typical start of the new users, these are very well received contributions and seem like a highly above average start.

You got your votes because your posts were considered good, but most of the votes didn't came from the reviews in the "first-posts" review queue. But the effect you suspect, partially exists, also in the FPQ and also for new contributors overall. It is up to voters/reviewers, how do they vote, if they vote. It seems you got mostly upvotes until now.

Some of the first-post reviewers, or anybody visiting the posts of new members, have the habit to vote down. Others have the habit to vote always up. I personally have the habit that I don't vote first-post questions always up, but I give upvotes for first posts very light-handedly. Thus, if the posts are not clearly bad, they get the up. I do this on these reasons:

- to compensate our wonderful community members with a strong downvoter habit, particularly targeting new user questions
- partially as a "welcome"
- and partially to motivate the new user to use the site more.

Internet communities tend to become more and more closed with time, and more and more antagonistic to the incomers. This is clearly visible also on the stats of the Stack Overflow since some years. I am trying to work against the phenomenon from inside. Doing that, I am volunteering hard work for the SO, to save the SO from itself.

Of course if it is clearly visible that the user doesn't even try to give his best, or his real problem is not the programming problem what he asks, but that he missed the elementary school, then I think he needs a clear feedback that *"so it won't go"*. And this is what I give him with my comments and votes.

Note, **only to vote in the first-post queue is a very bad thing**, don't forget this if you reach the 500! We also need to do many others, which is possible.

Many of the first posts will be closed on the reasons which are clear for us, but not for the newbie. The things which are required to be done, typically to save the post from the closure, i.e. to maximize the probability that the question of the user will be saved. These are:

- editing the post into a better form (particularly if it is clear to me, but not for the other voters)
- giving useful tips & tricks in comments, how to improve the post
- giving him psychological support, if his post will be likely unfairly closed (in my opinion)

You had luck with your first-post reviewers, and your posts were good. This is why you got so many upvotes now. But your posts won't be first-post reviewed any more, and the system is lesser friendly to you, but hopefully you will learn a lot to optimize your chances quickly.

Comment: "*If you are below 50 rep, your newly asked questions get into the "first-posts" review queue.*" the first sentence is already wrong... posts only get into First Post Review Queue if it's the user's *visible* first post, whether the user is a brand new 1-rep user, or 101-rep user from association bonus.

Comment: @AndrewT. I am not very sure in that. I've seen multiple first-posts from the same user many times already. Can you cite a reference for that?

Comment: The keyword is *visible*. You can get multiple first posts from the same user if all of their previous posts get deleted, making the next post the "first post".

Comment: This answer contains misinformation, it's not how the site works. Please take some guidance on how the site actually works.

Comment: @AndrewT. Right. I trink I fixed the post.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I tried to fix the post on Andrew's advice, while I tried to keep the essential meaning. Did you think on the same problem, or on some different?

Comment: @peterh that's an improvement, however this site has actually improved in its friendliness. This is something I have rallied for, as you know. There's evidence that there's been improvements, and hoping it will continue in that trajectory. So based on this, you're making some assumptions in your answer that may not be true.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes, it might be true, if there will be yet more advancement. The new CoC and the question wizard were imho very useful, I hope their effect will be soon visible on the SEDE stats, too.

Answer (score 29):

> #### Do asked questions get an upvote by default?

No, there's no such *"default upvote"*.

> I always get 5 reputation, whenever I ask a new question and the question also seems to have 1 vote score right when it's asked.

You should note that posting a question will be seen by a broad community of people very quickly at Stack Overflow.
Some of these people might choose to upvote or downvote your question (for whatever reasons) very quickly, so it appears to you that just the engine reacts in a time you can't believe a human reader might do.

> So if questions get a free upvote whenever they are first asked, which upvoter is it ascribed to in the system. The Community user?

You cannot know who upvoted your question, but it's definitely not the Community user or some other automatism.

> Does this system just grant 5 free reputation for every question asked?

As mentioned: No it doesn't.

> And why isn't this system abused?

A non existing mechanism can't be abused.

> Is it protected by a periodical limit?

Yes, asking questions is protected with a periodical limit for less trusted users. But that doesn't have to do anything with what you were asking about.

---

As I can tell from my personal behavior and experience:

- I am lurking at a specific tag (I am well experienced with) to see new incoming questions and judge how I should react.
- I'd probably downvote a question because I see even it's title leads to some very trivial and well known problem (lack of OP's research)
- If I see, the question deviates from the common search results, I might retract my downvote, and also retract close votes or duplicate closures within short time.
- Most of the time I also cast a close vote along with a downvote, if not I've closed a question for being an easy to find duplicate.

I often see community people reacting quite contrary and try to "balance out" downvotes with upvotes, just for empathy for new users, and not by judging the questions quality.

Also sometimes answers are given even for clearly *off-topic* or *duplicate* questions.

But well, all in all we have a community consensus how to handle new incoming questions (especially from newbs) here.
You might observe severely different behavior regarding tag specific communities.

Comment: *Some of these people might choose to upvote or downvote your question (for whatever reasons)* I am one of them even if I am not familiar to the technology for which the question is asked. I vote mainly for formatting in such questions.

Comment: @Gourav why would you do such a thing? Upvotes and downvotes are meant to be signals related to usefulness and perceived research effort, not formatting. Bad formatting can be fixed with an edit, but useless questions can also be well formatted.

Comment: I do edit them and vote them.

Comment: @Gourav but why are you voting based on formatting? That makes no sense. If you're not experienced enough in the technology to adequately assess usefulness and perceived research sffort, don't vote. Otherwise you're just casting nonsense votes that serve only to confuse matters.

Comment: @TinyGiant I can totally see how one, (beer and booze handy) might sit on the new tab of [tag:php] and after looking at 427 posts all of sudden stumble on a well-formatted post. Whether it is the scare, joy or excitement an  misclick might happen.